# Calculating the mean and variance of the following PDF

Tags: integration, statistics

There are $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n$ i.i.d normal random variables with the following pdf: $ky^2$ for $0 \le y \le 4$, find the value of $k$ and the mean and variances of the $Y_is$.

The value of $k$ is provided as the following:
$$k\int_0^4y^2dy \implies k[\frac{y^3}{3}]_0^4 \implies k = \frac{3}{64}$$

I'm not sure what the question is after when it asks for the $Y_is$?

I'm interpreting it as the following for the mean:

$$\frac{3}{64}\int_0^4 y^ny^2dy?$$

Comment: So $k$ is *negative*??  Try plotting your pdf.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I blundered ... I have fixed it - it was supposed to be y^2

Comment: They can't be normal *and* have that PDF. Anyway, the mean and variance of all of them is the same since they have the same distribution.

Comment: Please edit your question carefully, it doesn't follow normal distribution, also check what is your domain, are you having difficulty finding mean and variance?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh The original question says this exactly: "are i.i.d random variables with common p.d.f $P_y(y) = ky^2$". They used the range $0 \le y \le 2$ however, I assumed it wouldn't matter if it's a 4? Then it asks me to find the mean and variance of the $Y_is$. I'm unsure with the wording of the question and what it means by $Y_is$, I understand how to calculate a mean of a pdf but I'm not sure whether it's saying $y \cdot y^2$ or $y^n \cdot y^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not normal distributions.

Since $Y_i$'s are iid, they share a common mean and variance.

The question is asking for  what is this mean and the variance that is shared by these $Y_i$'s.

You can compute $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$ and then use the formula $Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$ to answer the question where the pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) =\begin{cases} ky^2, &0 \le y \le 4\\0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!